# Java, Android - App opens in Dark Mode first time launch of app when the device is set to Dark theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-darkmode

I am not sure if this is answered. When i install my app in a device with dark theme enabled, the first time launch is in dark mode. Is it because i use ?:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

So how to stop the app from doing that?
I have menu which user can select from which mode they want.

Comment: yes it is because of this , i do faced in normal mode also dark mode theme appearing, because of parent is same for both modes

Comment: To let the user choose, just remove DayNight. And use Theme.AppCompat for dark, Theme.AppCompat.Light for light.